# Is it possible to test a class' private method?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In my Ionic 3 (Angular 4) app I have this code:

```
this.$observable.subscribe(success => {
  if (success) {
    this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'message,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'middle'
    }).present();
  }
});
```

What I want to test is whether `toastCtrl` is called is `$observable` emits `success = true`.

This is what my test looks like:

```
it('when true, show toast', done => {
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    component.$observable.subscribe(success => {
      if (success) {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        console.log(debugElement.query(By.css('.toast-message')));
        done();
        // expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.toast-message')).nativeElement).toBeDefined();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

However it **doesn't work** as probably there is some delay in generating the toast (Note: I'm using Ionic Native but that element with that class is actually inserted in the DOM — even though just for 3 seconds and I tried even with 100s)

Am I doing something wrong in **testing async code**?

If not, **how do I test that `this.toastCtrl` is called** (apparently I cannot since it's a private property in component - as **necessary to get it to work as it's injected in the constructor as ...**

```
constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController)
```

Comment: @torazaburo can you be more precise?

Comment: @estus I don't see why it's a duplicated. it's the same concept, but from two different point of view and different cases

Comment: See the answer. It exactly answers your question about spying on private method. If there is private method in TypeScript, it can be accessed with Reflect.get or with `component['toastCtrl]`, and this is considered reflection.

Comment: @estus the original problem was different. Anyway, no problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test it using `spyOn` with pass-through.

You can also try `(component as any).privateMethod`. It's likely that `component['privateMethod']` would work too.

If the private method does not need access to `this`, you could put it outside the class, which you should probably do anyway.

In theory, you could expose a public version that works only if `jasmine` is defined:

```
public foo() {
  if (!jasmine) throw new Error("can't call this unless testing!"); 
  return bar();
}

private bar() {
  return 42;
}
```

Many other questions here on SO deal with this issue, and in particular the paradoxical notion of trying to test internal functions, which are supposed to be, well, internal, and thus presumably sort of black boxes.

Comment: All respect for this solution (I will try), but as far as I know having "test code" in the code to be tested isn't a great idea. makes sense?

Comment: It isn't a great idea to test internal things in the first place. They're internal because they're internal. They are irrelevant to the public interface, which is what you want to be testing. You should be able to change the internals without having to rewrite your unit tests. No one can use them directly, so it doesn't matter. If I had a function `function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }` that I was using in a sum function, as in `function sum(arr) { return arr.reduce(plus 0); }`, would you write a test for `plus`?

Comment: makes sense. As I said I will try (tomorrow). Would you give your 2 cents whether testing an async UI change with so much trouble would be worth it?

Comment: @dragonmnl Sorry, I can't understand your question.

Comment: What I mean is simply: do you think it's worth testing internals when necessary to test UI changes which depend on private properties? (as in my case)

Comment: the proposed method component['privateMethod'] has worked for me and it has made my life much better. For some might sound strange, but this is one of the best discoveries in terms of unit testing of the year. Now I am capable of providing always 100% coverage in my tests :) :) Thanks a lot to this user :)